# Why is 'echo on' not effective within an if clause in bat script?

Tags: batch-file, echo

With the following code,

```
echo off
if 1==1 (
    echo on
    pwd
)
```

I am expecting the following output,

```
C:\> echo off
pwd
C:/
```

but I am getting these.

```
C:\> echo off
C:/
```

Why is 'pwd' missing after I turn on echo again in the if clause?

Comment: What sort of batch file environment is this? Does `pwd` even exist on Windows?

Comment: (That being said, I think the echo applies to the whole `( ... )` expression.)

Comment: `Echo on/off` means to echo what you type, it does not affect program output. To Print to the screen use `echo message`. See `echo /?`.

Comment: The `IF` block of commands has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @jdv, just cmd.

Comment: @CatCat, I am confused by 'pwd' not echoed rather than 'C:/' (the result being echoed.

Comment: @Squshman, can you elaborate?

Comment: Brackets make your command one logical line. CMD processes lines one by one. The pwd in the line has already been echoed and suppressed as echo is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Full code**:

```
:: Read 1.
echo off

:: Echo off here and will affect Read 2.
@echo

:: Read 2.
if 1==1 (
    echo on
    cd
)

:: Echo on here and will affect Read 3.
@echo

:: Read 3.
cd
```

3 reads from the interpreter are the focus of this code.
`@echo` is ignored as a actual read as it is just to show
the current `echo` state for testing.

The **1st read** is:

```
echo off
```

As the script starts as default with `echo on`, then this read will be displayed with `echo on`.

The **2nd read** is:

```
if 1==1 (
    echo on
    cd
)
```

The parentheses causes a multiline code block so it is read as one read.
The execution of the `echo on` will have no effect until the next read.
It is too late for the `echo on` in this code block to affect the
current read as it has already been read.

The **3rd read** is:

```
cd
```

The `echo on` of the 2nd read will affect the 3rd read and will `echo`
the command `cd` before executing the command.